# Angular 2: Prevent routing to new page if the service fails

Tags: angular, angular-services

In my Angular 2 app

**home.html**

```
<div>
<nav>
    <a [routerLink]="['Users']">Users</a>
</nav>
</div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {Router,RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES,RouterOutlet} from 'angular2/router';
import {UsersComponent} from './users/users'

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, RouterOutlet]
})
@RouteConfig([
{
    path: '/users',
    name: 'Users',
    component: UsersComponent
}
])
export class AppComponent { 

constructor(private _router:Router) {}
}
```

**users.ts**

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {NgForm} from 'angular2/common';
import {DataService} from '../service';

@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
templateUrl: 'views/user.html'
})

export class UsersComponent {

constructor(private dataService: DataService) {
    this.dataService.getUserList().subscribe(
            (res) => {
                console.log('response=>' + res);
            },
            (error) => {
                console.log('failure);
            });
}
}
```

If there is any failure in service I want to prevent routing to the user.html page.

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

[CanActivate](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/CanActivate-decorator.html) is the right lifecycle callback to do this.

Currently using DI in `@CanActivate()` requires an ugly workaround (https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4112) but the Angular team is working on improving that.

Comment: Could you please post how to use CanActivate with my code?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/SF8gsYN1SvmUbkosHjqQ?p=preview shouldn't be too hard to adapt to your code.